# How to make multiple buttons open different Activities

Tags: android

I followed the guide online and was able to make one button open another activity. However, I am running into problems when following links on here to try and code more than one button to open a different activity for each button.  My code I have so far is below, and I can't figure out why I am getting errors.

```
    package com.example.poweruser.fcemsandroid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.protocolbutton);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asabutton);

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {

        public void onclick(View view) {
            Intent aspirin = new Intent(this, aspirin.class);
            startActivity(aspirin);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is error..?

Comment: aspirin activity, defined in Manifest?

Comment: yes it is. And the errors are: 1) *Error:(21, 59) error: <anonymous com.example.poweruser.fcemsandroid.HomeScreen$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener"
and 2 ***"Error:(24, 34) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<aspirin>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Cont*

Comment: @beans217 share your whole activity code

Comment: @beans217 try this `Intent aspirin = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, aspirin.class);`

Comment: Still didn't work. Is the code for the Onclicklistener correct?

Comment: @beans217 try this `Intent aspirin2 = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, aspirin.class);
            startActivity(aspirin2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **Typo** check it

its **`onClick(View view)`** not **`onclick(View view)`**

Use this

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent aspirin2 = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, aspirin.class);
            startActivity(aspirin2);
            }
        });
```

Instead of  this

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {

    public void onclick(View view) {
        Intent aspirin = new Intent(this, aspirin.class);
        startActivity(aspirin);
    }
});
```

Comment: "Error:(21, 59) error: <anonymous com.example.poweruser.fcemsandroid.HomeScreen$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener"

Comment: That was it so far. Running the app to see if the code works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent aspirin = new Intent(this, aspirin.class);
        startActivity(aspirin);
    }
});
```

The problem probably was that the abstract method for OnClickListener is

> onClick()

not without a capital 'C'

> onclick()

Comment: That was it! thank you! can't believe one simple capital letter gave me such a headache of what I was doing wrong; thank you for helping! Mind telling me what the first error was in regards to? what I did that I shouldn't do in the future?

Comment: @beans217 do you still have errors?
The first error occurred because of the capitalization mistake itself.. 
since `onClick()` is an abstract method of the onClickListener it pretty much could not override it manually because `onClick()` was never found on your code as it was `onclick()`

Answer (score 1):

error 1

you should override `onClick()` instead of `onclick()`

error 2

use `HomeScreen.this` instead of `this` while declaring Intent

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent aspirin2 = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, aspirin.class);
    startActivity(aspirin2);
}});
```

Comment: to avoid typo do ctrl+o to override methods